# how to export in excell sheet the entire view rather than only list in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my below code I want  to display all the data in excell sheet but not only a specific list ( i have comment it). My view content different list  from different model and they are in a recursive way , there are partial view too. so i need to grap whole content of view ( whatever is seen on that view) and export it in excel . How can i do it?

```
public ActionResult ExportVchrReport(BillVoucher obj)
        {
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Type","application/vnd.ms-excel");
            //var ls=(List<BillVoucher>)TempData["VchrRpt"];
            //TempData["VchrRpt"]=ls;
            //return View(ls);
            var data = TempData["myModel"];
            return View(data);
        }
```

Comment: How your view look like?

Comment: it uses one list from  bv.lstbllvchr = bv.getBillTransByDate(obj); and it display some data and taking their id it call controller by renderaction and generate another list. like in a recursive way